# RSA_verify Returns zero. with error Algorithm:mismatch

Tags: java, openssl, cryptography, rsa, digital-signature

I sign the Message using Java IBMFIPS compliant.
The code to sign the message is:

```
//Signs the hash of each chunk and adds it to the Message Header
//data is 256Kb length  
//Get private key function is created by me to read the DER key formated file
GetPrivateKey privkey = new GetPrivateKey();   
Signature genSign = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSA","IBMJCEFIPS");
genSign.initSign(privkey.get());
genSign.update(data.getBytes());
byte[] byteSignedData = genSign.sign();
```

Get Private Key function code

```
File privateKeyFile = new File("Certificates" + File.separator+"mykey.der");
byte[] encodedKey = new byte[(int)privateKeyFile.length()];
new FileInputStream(privateKeyFile).read(encodedKey);
PKCS8EncodedKeySpec privateKeySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(encodedKey);
KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA","IBMJCEFIPS");
RSAPrivateCrtKey privatekey = (RSAPrivateCrtKey).generatePrivate(privateKeySpec);
return privatekey;
```

I am verifying this signature using openssl 0.9.8g,  RSA_Verify() function.

I got the Error as:

> RSA_verify_PKCS1 failed with error
>   error:04077064:rsa routines:RSA_verify:algorithm mismatch

Comment: Call OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms before calling this function. It might help you.